# How to convert function to script method?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-5.0

I have a powershell function, is there any way to convert it into a script method?

```
function Do-Something {
  Param( 
     $p1,
     $p2
     )
 [...]
}
```

I am trying to convert it to script method in below fashion, but it throws exception.

```
$obj | add-member-membertype scriptmethod { $function:Do-Something }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code shows two examples. In my opinion the first Add-Member shows better approach which is more OOP.

```
function Convert-PersonToText
{
    param($Person)
    '{0} {1}' -f $Person.FirstName, $Person.LastName
}

function Print-Something
{
    Write-Host 'Something'
}

function New-Person
{
    param($FirstName, $LastName)

    $result = '' | select FirstName, LastName
    $result.FirstName = $FirstName
    $result.LastName = $LastName
    Add-Member -InputObject $result -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name 'ToText' -Value { Convert-PersonToText -Person $this }
    Add-Member -InputObject $result -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name 'Print' -Value ((Get-Command -Name 'Print-Something').ScriptBlock)
    $result
}


$person = New-Person -FirstName 'John' -LastName 'Smith'
$person.ToText() | Out-Host
$person.Print()
```

Output:

```
John Smith
Something
```

Comment: @fdafdaf can function in another module be used here?

Comment: In second Add-Member approach you can use only script modules (not binary modules). In the first Add-Member example you can use anything.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach (you can mix it with @fdafadf solution):

```
function Do-Something { param($p1) Write-Host $p1 }
$obj = @{}
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name "DoSomething" -Value ${function:Do-Something}
$obj.DoSomething(3)
```

Comment: Dyl how to param in this approach?

Comment: There is already a param. `DoSomething(3)` is called, 3 becomes $p1 and goes directly to `Write-Host`

Comment: oh then while defining we can just add the function name. While calling we can pass param. Isn’t it? Will this approach works if function is in different file ( or in different psm1)?